# Чопорность и пуризм

Tags: лексикон, выбор-слова

В чем отличние между данными словами?

**пуризм**

> Чрезмерное стремление к чистоте и строгости нравов (иногда показное). 
>   Излишняя строгость в соблюдении каких-либо правил.

**чопорность**

> от чопорный = Чрезмерно, неестественно строгий в поведении и в
>   обращении; крайне щепетильный в отношении соблюдения приличий.

Comment: Пуризм может быть по отношению к себе, но совсем необязательно может требовать этого от других (например, "я делаю так как считаю нужным, а вы как хотите так и делайте"). А чопорный человек с подчеркнутым неодобрением будет относиться ко всем кто делает "не так как положено".

Comment: @Artemix А вы можете оформить это в виде отдельного ответа? Просто за ответы можно голосовать, и может он понравится сообществу настолько, что выйдет на первое место. Тогда для тех, кто ищет ответ на вопрос, ваш самый релевантный ответ будет на первом месте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чопорность проявляется в поведении, а пуризм - в отношении, во взглядах. Есть пуристы в лингвистике, в программировании, хоть в боевых искусствах, это понятие можно применить почти к любой сфере деятельности, включая данный сайт. А чопорность касается именно поведения в обществе, это сродни заносчивости, излишней щепетильности. Пурист может вести себя чопорно, но это **совершенно** необязательно. Можно сказать, что чопорность это пуризм нравов.

Comment: А может быть чопорность без пуризма?

Comment: И ещё. Чем тогда чопорность отличается от жеманства?

Comment: Может ли быть чопорность без пуризма это наполовину философский вопрос. Если определять ее как пуризм нравов, то, разумеется, не может. Чопорность может быть чисто показной, а на деле (наедине с самим собой или в семье) этот человек может быть полной свиньей. Тогда это без пуризма, я думаю :). Жеманство часто (но не всегда) связано с кокетством, оно "должно" привлекать, а чопорность скорее должна отталкивать. Жеманство и заносчивость несовместимы, а чопорность и заносчивость очень близки.

Answer (score 1):

Большинство словарей определяет **чопорность** как слово, производное от **чопорный**, то есть это, в первую очередь личностная характеристика - это не "идеология".

> **ЧО́ПОРНЫЙ**. Чрезмерно, неестественно строгий в поведении, обращении, *крайне щепетильный в отношении приличий*. Чопорная вежливость. Чопорно (нареч.) держаться. [Толковый словарь Ушакова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1089034). 1935-1940.

Крайняя щепетильность в отношении приличий у чопорного человека распространяется в том числе и на окружающих - если кто-то делает что-то не так - чопорный человек будет относится к этому с явным неодобрением.

В качестве иллюстрации можно вспомнить "чопорных англичан", про которых существует множество анекдотов, и образ джентльмена многократно воспроизведенный в кино и литературе.

**Пуризм** от чопорности отличается тем, что может распространятся не только на строгость соблюдения приличий, но и на соблюдение некого набора правил вообще.

> Например [Никлаус Вирт](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82,_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81), создатель нескольких языков программирования, является пуристом в отношении принципов структурного программирования. Он не включил в язык Pascal оператор безусловного перехода goto, и считает что объекты (основа объектно-ориентированного программмирования) - это всего-навсего структуры содержащие данные и указатели на функции - не более того. (См. также описание его [научных принципов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82,_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D1.83.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.BF.D1.8B))

Если же говорить говорить о пуризме как о "соблюдении приличий", то здесь тоже возможен пуризм как личная характеристика, так и пуризм по отношению к другим (например, стиль воспитания). Во втором случае пуризм может использоваться как синоним пуританства:

> Иногда пуризм доходит до таких размеров, что из рук девушки вырывают всякий роман, всякую книгу, в которой встречается слово «любовь». Писарев, Дворянское гнездо. Роман И. С. Тургенева. [Малый академический словарь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/56594/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC).

"Пурист" может не требовать строгости нравов от других, строгость в поведении может быть его личным выбором. В этом случае строгость в поведении может характеризовать образ жизни человека в целом, а не только умение "держать себя в обществе". Толковый словарь иностранных слов в качестве синонимов пуризма приводит аскетизм, пуританизм и ригоризм:

> **ПУРИ́ЗМ**, а, мн. нет, м. [фр. purisme < лат. pūris чистый].1.Стремление к чистоте и строгости нравов, иногда показное.||Ср. аскетизм (во 2-м знач.), пуританизм (во 2-м знач.), ригоризм.
>   АСКЕТИ́ЗМ ... 2. Вообще крайнее воздержание, отказ от жизненных благ.
>   ПУРИТАНИ́ЗМ ... 2. перен. Строгий образ жизни, неукоснительное следование строгим нравственным нормам.
>   РИГОРИ́ЗМ, Чрезмерная строгость, прямолинейность в соблюдении нравственных принципов, в поведении.
>   [Толковый словарь иноязычных слов. — 2004](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/)